# Python import rules on Django example

Tags: python, python-import

I'm confused about how does Python `import` its classes. Looking into Django's source I can see a module named `django.views.generic` with few `.py` files in it, like: `base.py`, `list.py` or `edit.py`.

Now, if I would like to `import ListView` `class` (defined in `list.py`) I could do:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
```

but the following would work as well:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
```

Question: is there any difference between those two?

And does Python treat files like different modules named as the files?

Comment: You can use `is` to check if they have the same identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/__init__.py) file, you will see that it imports the classes for you. So when you do

`from django.views.generic import ListView`

you are actually importing the class from the `__init__.py` file and not from `django.views.generic.list`

Also, have a look at [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

So there is practically no difference, in both ways you will end up with identical objects.

Comment: Whenever you import a Python package, e.g. ``django.views.generic``, the package's ``__init__.py`` is run. In this case, as @Visgean Skeloru pointed out, the ``__init__.py`` file imports ``ListView`` into ``django.views.generic``'s namespace. So, you are free to import the exact same class from either location.

Comment: You might want to add some information on the asker's other question: *And does Python treat files like different modules named as the files?* In Python a module is a file. [The Python docs say](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), *A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix ``.py`` appended.*